# rewrite a query string for a particular page

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite my URL from example.com/page/pipe?test to example.com/page/pipe/test

My concept is just to remove the? at the end of the page and replace it with a /
And I have written a rule to remove the .php extension of my files. below is what code looks like

```
#REMOVE THE FILE EXTENSION FROM THE URL ESPECIALLY .PHP
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Remove ? from /page/pipe.php? and replace it with /page/pipe/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) pipe.php?$1 [QSA]
```

my previous code that removes .php makes is possible for my site to be accessed either example.com/page or example.com/page/

but I want every query in pipe.php to be converted to /
so that I will have pipe.php?test converted to pipe/test

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _“will have pipe.php?test converted to pipe/test”_ - are you sure you don’t mean the other way around …? What do you want your links to point to, what do you want users to see in the browser address bar?

Comment: What i want is to simply remove the ? That goes before every query, and also the php extension in the url, so the link will now open as example. com/page/pipe/anything instead of example. com/page/pipe.php/anything

Comment: Well then start by including the `pipe` part in your rule pattern. Right now, you would be _matching_ the `pipe` part of `page/pipe`, and rewrite that to `pipe.php?pipe`.

Comment: @CBroe can you please show me some  code or how to go about it